# Java listener for mouse click on any textbox on the screen

Tags: java, textbox, mouseevent, on-screen-keyboard

Is there a way for Java to listen to another program for mouse clicks?

If so, is there a way to listen for mouse clicks on text inputs on other programs?

I'm making an on screen keyboard for a project I'm working on. It will automatically be displayed when the user selects any text input on the screen. When the text input is unfocused, the keyboard would disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, in Java there is no way to detect Mouse or Keyboard events when your application is not in focus. This is a security mechanism that is built into Java.

An application cannot listen for these events unless it has root (admin) privileges anyway.

Comment: How would I go about writing a program to do this?

Comment: You would have to probably write a service and then have the service supply the information to your application.